# Seeing more information when looking at camel routes using hawtio

Tags: apache-camel, hawtio

I have a Camel route with a `choice` and a few `when` predicates. It works well. But when I look in the route using hawtio, I can't actually tell what is is doing.

Example:

[image]

Is there anything I can add to the route to be able to describe what the `when`'s are comparing against?